# Adding new row datagridview to use default values

Tags: sql, visual-studio, t-sql, data-binding

I have the following SQL that creates a table and inserts the first row of data without a problem.  The default DateTime values are also inserted as expected.

```
CREATE TABLE Jobs (
[Id]       int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
[JobName]      nvarchar(256) Default 'SomeName', 
[CreateDate]     DateTime DEFAULT GETDATE(),
[ModifyDate]     DateTime DEFAULT GETDATE(),
[LastOpenDate]     DateTime DEFAULT GETDATE(),
[CreatedByUser]     nvarchar(64) Default 'SomeUser',
[Title]       nvarchar(256) Default 'SomeTitle')
GO
INSERT INTO Jobs (JobName)
VALUES ('NewName')
GO
```

In Visual Studio 2008 I am using the DataGridView and BindingNavigator controls.  When I add a new row the default values are not inserted but nulls are inserted instead.  I think this is something to do with the controls but not sure how to get the default values to be used.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you inserting via data source or some other methodology ??

Comment: I am adding using a datasource.

Answer (score 6):

You can [set the default values for the Datagridview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b22t666e.aspx) on the DefaultValuesNeeded event

eg:

```
private void dataGridView1_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender,
    System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells["Region"].Value = "WA";
    e.Row.Cells["City"].Value = "Redmond";
    e.Row.Cells["PostalCode"].Value = "98052-6399";
    e.Row.Cells["Region"].Value = "NA";
    e.Row.Cells["Country"].Value = "USA";
    e.Row.Cells["CustomerID"].Value = NewCustomerId();
}
```